# command line arguments to Installanywhere build exe

Tags: installanywhere

how can I pass a command line argument to build.exe to specify where is the source folder to be included in the installer?

Answer (score 1):

Add an environment variable for the source path, prepended with IA_PATH_ tag. For example, to set the source path SOURCE_PATH, set the environment variable IA_PATH_SOURCE_PATH. and access it as $SOURCE_PATH$

Comment: Thanks. I was searching for this for 2 days.